# logcat-No connected devices on my Second and third Android Studio versions

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, adb, logcat

I have three versions of Android Studio (Chipmunk | 2021.2.1, Giraffe | 2022.3.1, Iguana | 2023.2.1). I can run my apps on the emulator without any problem, and also, the logcat in the Chipmunk version works well. However, the logcat in the two other versions doesn't recognize my emulators (Nox, google Pixel 2).

I tried kill-server and restarting ADB and other solutions on Stack Overflow, but they didn't work for me! Could it be related to having multiple versions of Android Studio? When I tried to install and run my app on a real device (Android Studio Iguana), it wouldn't even install.

Comment: No matter how many Studios you have, there always be a single `adb` listening on the default port (unless you specify another).